# Is this use case of CRTP considered undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, memory, undefined-behavior, crtp

I'm trying to build a message in a fixed size buffer where a user of my library provides some of the data within it. I used to do this by giving the user a pointer to the buffer and letting them write into it, and set a `size_t` argument by reference to the number of bytes they wrote. I wanted to move away from this approach because it allows the user to accidentally corrupt the buffer, or incorrectly report the number of bytes written. In order to do this, I did the following:

Defined this struct:

```
template <class Derived>
struct MsgBase
{
    size_t size() const { return sizeof(Derived); }
    const char* data() const {
        const Derived* dat = static_cast<const Derived*>(this);
        return reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dat);
    }
};
```

And I require that if the user wants to send certain data, that they define a struct inheriting from this with the data to be sent. For example:

```
struct Example : MsgBase<Example>
{
    int a;
    double b;
    char c[7];
};
```

I have this class defined to help them communicate the data to my library:

```
class Loader
{
public:
    Loader() : size(0), data(0) {}

    size_t size() const { return size; }
    const char* data() const { return data; }

    template<class T> void loadData(const T& t) {
        size = t.size();
        data = t.data();
    }

private:
    size_t size;
    const char* data;
};
```

And so I call them like this:

```
{
    //pos is a char* to a point in a buffer of data
    Loader loader;
    onLibraryCall(&loader);
    memcpy(pos, loader.data(), loader.size());
}
```

And the user is doing this:

```
void onLibraryCall(Loader* loader)
{
    Example e;
    e.a = 3;
    e.b = 2.7;
    e.c[0] = //bla fill out some stuff here

    loader->loadData(e);
}
```

This has worked in countless binaries that I have tested with compiled using different versions of gcc but corrupts the message above consistently in one particular binary. gdb and valgrind have not helped me at all and the issue goes away if I try to log what is happening right around the calls above. This makes me think there is undefined behavior in this but I'm not entirely sure where that could be or what I could do to further debug it?

**I have a check to make sure any such defined structs are POD. I also know what all the structs are and currently they are all a combination of only integral types and fixed size small arrays.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Loader::loadData()` you store a copy of the argument's `this` pointer via `MsgBase::data()`.

In `onLibraryCall()`, you allocate an `Example` instance on the stack, then pass a reference to it to `Loader::loadData()`. The `Example` instance goes out of scope at the end of this function and is destroyed.

In the calling code, after `onLibraryCall()` returns, the `memcpy()` call reads from the pointer that was cached in `Loader::loadData()`, but that pointer is now pointing to a memory address that is no longer in use, so you have Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behavior if you cannot guarantee that all classes derived from `MsgBase` will be Plain Old Data (POD).

The moment a derived class contains a pointer, you're sending raw pointers to the network or a file, which is useless and probably deadly when you reload the buffer's contents and try to make sense of it.

Anything that's not POD should be properly serialized, rather than sent raw across process boundaries.

---

Be careful with who allocates what, too (new/delete vs malloc vs new byte[]/delete[]...)

Comment: Good point. I do have a check for that and I know that all of the structs (there are only 4) that exist now are POD. They are not very different from Example above actually. The message gets corrupted before it is serialized, and it only happens on a single binary but works well on dozens of others. Also, there is no allocation here, it is stack and memcopied.